# SignalR in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, signalr.client

I'm trying to make use of SignalR in Android Studio and while it apparently has added the projects and dependencies to my application project I'm getting constant

Error:(11, 39) error: package microsoft.aspnet.signalr.client does not exist

The import for these packages was dynamically added by Android studio as I started typing code to make use of it

```
    Platform.loadPlatformComponent(new AndroidPlatformComponent());
```

So there is something there.

However when I try and actually build my main project I keep getting the package error.

I've run out of ideas now as to why it can know enough about the project to build it and reference the packages but then not actually find those packages for the main project to use.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am half-way done toward getting this to work. Reply if you want updates as I solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never did find out how to do it via Android Studio.  In the end I had to use Eclipse (and don't forget to change your workspace to use Java 1.6 or greater)